# how to merge values of array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Handle] => example-t-shirt
            [Title] => Example T-Shirt            
            [Vendor] => Acme
            [Type] => Shirts
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Handle] => example-t-shirt
            [Title] => 1
            [Vendor] => 2
            [Type] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Handle] => example-t-shirt
            [Title] => 4
            [Vendor] => 5
            [Type] => 6
        )

)
```

I have this array and i want to convert it like

```
Array
(
    [Handle] => example-t-shirt,example-t-shirt,example-t-shirt
    [Title] => Example T-Shirt,1,4
    [Vendor] => Acme,2,5
    [Type] => Shirts,3,6
)
```

one thing more key of array like handle or title are also not fixed these are also dynamic.
thanx in advance

Comment: This is transformation of array. Can you show the code please? Looks like you can do this using two nested `foreach` loops and `.join()`.

Comment: could you rephrase *one thing more key of array like handle or title are also not fixed these are also dynamic* ? it seems very unclear to me

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to generate it as an array:

```
<?php
    $mainArray = array(
        array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-shirt",
            "Title" => "Example T-Shirt",
            "Vendor" => "Acme",
            "Type" => "Shirts"
        ),
        array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-pant",
            "Title" => "Example T-Pant",
            "Vendor" => "Meca",
            "Type" => "Pants"
        )
    );
    $finalArray = array(
        "Handle" => array(),
        "Title" => array(),
        "Vendor" => array(),
        "Type" => array()
    );
    foreach ($mainArray as $current)
        foreach ($current as $key => $value)
            $finalArray[$key][] = $value;
?>
```

And later, each one in the `$finalArray` should be joined.

```
foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value)
    $finalArray[$key] = implode(", ", $value);
```

So your final code will be:

```
<?php
    $mainArray = array(
        array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-shirt",
            "Title" => "Example T-Shirt",
            "Vendor" => "Acme",
            "Type" => "Shirts"
        ),
        array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-pant",
            "Title" => "Example T-Pant",
            "Vendor" => "Meca",
            "Type" => "Pants"
        )
    );
    $finalArray = array(
        "Handle" => array(),
        "Title" => array(),
        "Vendor" => array(),
        "Type" => array()
    );
    foreach ($mainArray as $current)
        foreach ($current as $key => $value)
            $finalArray[$key][] = $value;
    foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value)
        $finalArray[$key] = implode(", ", $value);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Handle] => example-t-shirt, example-t-pant
    [Title] => Example T-Shirt, Example T-Pant
    [Vendor] => Acme, Meca
    [Type] => Shirts, Pants
)
```

**Fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8LFSZk**

Comment: keys of array are not fixed like not sure every time keys are handle,title or vendor these are dynamic depends on data of csv file which user import.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with array_walk_recursive

```
$mainArray = array(
        array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-shirt",
            "Title" => "Example T-Shirt",
            "Vendor" => "Acme",
            "Type" => "Shirts"
        ),
        array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-pant",
            "Title" => "Example T-Pant",
            "Vendor" => "Meca",
            "Type" => "Pants"
        )
    );

$final = array();

array_walk_recursive($mainArray, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
  $final[$key] = isset($final[$key]) ?  $item .', '. $final[$key] : $item;
});

var_dump($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$temp = array(
    array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-shirt",
            "Title" => "Example T-Shirt",          
            "Vendor" => "Acme",
            "Type" => "Shirts"
          ),

    array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-shirt",
            "Title" => 1,
            "Vendor" => 2,
            "Type" => 3
        ),

    array(
            "Handle" => "example-t-shirt",
            "Title" => 4,
            "Vendor" => 5,
            "Type" => 6
    )
);

$result = array();

foreach($temp as $t){
  if (is_array($t)){
    foreach ($t as $k=>$r){
        if(array_key_exists($k,$result)){
            $result[$k] .= ','.$r;
        } else {
            $result[$k] = $r;
        }
    }
  }
}
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($result);
?>
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/504620)